# Strange NullPointerException Catch in OpenJDK JAXB Implementation

Tags: jaxb, nullpointerexception, java

I found some strange code in OpenJDK JAXB:

com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder

```java
    try {
        XmlSchema s = null;
        s.location();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // as expected
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
        ...
    }
```

Can some explain why they do this? Or this is just a bad code need to fix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are using this code as a test to determine which version of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) APIs are being used.  The `location` parameter was added to `@XmlSchema` in JAXB 2.1, if `NoSuchMethodError` was thrown then JAXB 2.0 APIs are being used.

**See Lines 158-177**

- http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jvnet.jaxb.reflection/jaxb2-reflection/2.1.4/org/jvnet/jaxb/reflection/model/impl/ModelBuilder.java

**Javadoc - @XmlSchema.location**

- [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html#location()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema.html#location%28%29)

Comment: I have nothing against NoSuchMethodError, but why it is necessary generate NPE? Why not call location method on  some static XmlSchema instance. NPE complicates debugging.