# Why does Sun prefer NoSuchMethodError + NullPointerException instead of Class inspection?

Tags: java, reflection

I did a small debug session and stumbled over the following code snippet in Sun/Oracle's code:

```
try {
        XmlSchema s = null;
        s.location();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // as epxected
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError e) {
         // this is not a 2.1 API. Where is it being loaded from?
         ...
    }
```

I think this has several flaws by first of all expecting a `NullPointerException`, using `((XmlSchema)null).location();` and expecting a `NoSuchMethodError`. If I would do the code review I would flag this as unappropriated code by triggering an exception as a regular event.

In my opinion using `XmlSchema.getClass().getMethod("location", new Object[0])` would be a some what better idea.

Since this code is used in the official API implementation I wonder if there are edge cases, I am not aware of which prevent class inspection being a good solution and one has to use this code snippet as a fall back.

UPDATE:

This question is related to ["Strange NullPointerException CATCH in OpenJDK JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13693577/strange-nullpointerexception-catch-in-openjdk-jaxb-implementation) but it is not answering my question about the why do they do it. It is just an explaination what it does not about why they do it.

UPDATE2:

Using the test code:

```
@Test
public void test() throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Method method = ArrayList.class.getMethod("size");
    if(method == null)
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

and

```
@Test
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void test2() {
    ArrayList<?> list = null;
    try {
        list.size();
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e) {
    }
    catch(NoSuchMethodError e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

I found that TestNG reports 0s for both tests (after you warm up). Since the code is executed within a static method of a class this code is executed at most once.

So the timing is not the reason. Another problem is that a modern compiler detects the attempt to execute the location method on a null reference and therefore one need to suppress the execution.

So the timing is not the reason (anymore?) for preferring this hack instead of a proper class inspection.

Does anyone know more answers to this?

Comment: In which specific class did you find this code? Which version?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a catch for handling the NoSuchMethodError, the slow code is used exceptionally. If instead you use reflection for checking the existence of the method, then the slow code is always used.

Comment: I tested the timing and the timing is the same 0sec. Since this method is executed once within a static method this might were the reason 15 years ago but is not longer valid.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the code fragment is now referred to as old legacy code that was never maintained in the meantime. Especially if one notice that any modern IDE flags this code snippet as a accessing a NULL reference.

The reason for using this might have been the problems with reflections (slow) 15 years ago but at least today do not make sense anymore.

Also generating a NullPointerException everytime within the normal application flow and therefore generate such an important exception and unnecessarily interfere with a debug session this can be considered a defect.

So final conlusion: Do not use this code snippet to verify a compatible class version, use reflection instead.